# General Strategies for Convergence of Complex iterations.

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Its easy to prove the convergence of this iteration for positive real numbers:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+pb_n}{p+1}\quad\quad b_{n+1}=\sqrt[m]{a_{n+1}^m-(a_{n+1}-b_n)^m}$$
because for any choice of $p,m\ge 1$ it turns out that $a_n$ and $b_n$ sandwich each other. Meaning one of the following is true after some point in the iteration:
$$a_n\ge a_{n+1}\ge b_{n+1}\ge b_n \quad\text{or}\quad a_n<a_{n+1}<b_{n+1}<b_n$$
So $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge and the equation defining $a_{n+1}$ ensures that they converge to the same value. So what I'm wondering is:

> Can this kind of proof be extended to the complex numbers?

The problem is even if it could be shown that $|a_n|<|a_{n+1}|<|b_{n+1}|<|b_n|$, this would still not ensure that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are converging at all $-$ much less converging to each other. It only shows that their lengths are converging.

For anyone curious, when $m=2$ and $p=1$ this iteration is the Arithmetic-Geometric-Mean.

Answer (score 0):

This seems impossible.

For converge to be possible then consider the expression for $b_{n+1}$ and set $a_{\infty}=b_{\infty}=c_0$.  Then :

$$c_0 = \left( c_0^m -( c_0-c_0)^m \right)^{\frac 1 m}$$

which means :

$$c_0 = \left({c_0^m}\right)^{\frac 1 m}$$

But in general $\left({c_0^m}\right)^{\frac 1 m}$ has $m$ distinct complex roots and they all have equal standing.

Let's just take $m=2$ as an example.

The roots of $c_0^2=r^2 e^{i2\theta}$ will be :

$$z_{\pm} = \pm r e^{i \theta }$$

But these clearly don't converge.

So in general we can't expect a convergence from these series.

Comment: But what if we restrict $a_0$ and $b_0$ to lie in the region of the plane bounded from from above by $\zeta=sin(\pi/2m)+icos(\pi/2m)$ and from below by $\bar{\zeta}$. And then choose the root that lies in that region at each step in the iteration?